# In C#, can I set some httpclienthandler properties in Restsharp?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp, dotnet-httpclient

I have the following code in C# that uses HTTPClient and I am trying to migrate to [RestSharp](http://restsharp.org/) to leverage the nice Derserialization code

here is my current code:

```
 var httpClient = new HttpClient(new HttpClientHandler()
        {
            UseDefaultCredentials = true,
            AllowAutoRedirect = false
        });

 var response = httpClient.GetStringAsync(myUrl).Result;
```

Here is the equivalent code using restsharp:

```
 _client = new RestClient { BaseUrl =new Uri(myUrl) };
 var request = new RestRequest { Method = method, Resource = "/project", RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json };
 var response = _client.Execute(request);
```

but I can't figure out how to set

```
 UseDefaultCredentials = true
```

and

```
 AllowAutoRedirect = false
```

on the restSharp side.  Is this supported?

Comment: Why not just port the deserializer over for use with HttpClient?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need provide the basic authentication information like below for RestSharp if you want to use the Basic HTTP authentication.

```
 _client = new RestClient { BaseUrl =new Uri(myUrl) };
_client.Authenticator = new HttpBasicAuthenticator("<username>", "<password>");
```

To use the windows authentication:

> **Update**:

```
    const Method httpMethod = Method.GET;
    string BASE_URL = "http://localhost:8080/";

    var client = new RestClient(BASE_URL);
    // This property internally sets the AllowAutoRedirect of Http webrequest
    client.FollowRedirects = true;
    // Optionally you can also add the max redirects 
    client.MaxRedirects = 2;

    var request = new RestRequest(httpMethod)
    {
        UseDefaultCredentials = true
    };

    client.Execute(request);
```

Comment: thanks . . any ideas about setting:AllowAutoRedirect